# .Xib creates error when running the project with Xcode 4.6.1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode5, xcode4.6

Please someone help me out.

MY Mac OS(10.8.5) is updated and me also using the Xcode 5, but i have my previous Xcode 4.6.1 also installed in my mac. When i run my project through Xcode 5 then it's OK but when i run my project through Xcode 4.6.1 then it show that error which you seen in the image.and can't run the project.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has a very simple answer.

Open the Project file on Xcode 5, And then

```
1.Open file inspector

2.On Interface Builder Documents section change Open with to Xcode 4.6 (if it's 5.x).
```

[image]

```
3.Click Revert, Close the project and open that with old Xcode.
```

[image]

you can do the same thing on Xcode 4.6 to work with older version.

Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 3):

1)Goto your xcode5 see your StoryBoardFile go to Assistant Editor preview option.

2)Then Goto  file inspector see first tab

3)Select your interface Builder Documents 4.6

4) One Alert popup they ask you Revert to Xcode 4.6 format? select Revert

Follow this step and open your project in your old xcode project.